# Save lines from file into new string. C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I need to save lines from a text file into a string and then insert them into a data structure, but with my solution (which I assume is really bad) - I only save words into my `line`.

```
    FILE * ifile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    while(fscanf(ifile, "%s\n", line) == 1) {
        //inserting "line" into data structure here - no problem with that one
   }
```

Comment: `"%s\n"` --> `" %[^\n]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always a bad idea to use the [fscanf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) function as it can leave your file pointer in an unknown location on failure.

You should use [fgets()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) to get each line.

```
#define SIZE_LINE 256
FILE *ifile = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
if (ifile != NULL) {
    while (fgets (buff, SIZE_LINE, ifile)) {
        /* //inserting "line" into data structure here */
    }
    fclose (ifile);
}
```